# jquery ".prop()" does not work before appending to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jquery to create an initially blank `select` element. I tried this:

```
$('<select><option>1<option>2</select>').prop('selectedIndex', -1).appendTo(document.body);
```

This successfully creates a select box, but it is not blank. Through experimenting, i found out that this works:

```
var $new = $('<select><option>1<option>2</select>').appendTo(document.body);
$new.prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

What is different between those two is that when the`selectedIndex` property is set: before or after it is appended to the body. Can you explain reason beneath this?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/317/

Comment: @Blender it works if you set it to `1`, not for `-1`.

Comment: It's not a jQuery-specific problem: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/318/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/320/ works for me on Firefox. Seems like a Chrome issue.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Firefox is the only browser that does it. Chrome, Opera and IE10 have the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It just looks to me like the $.prop() function must run after the item is appended to the body. Here's an example using your first code: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/R9auG/311/

And the code itself:

```
$('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>')
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

PS - You are not closing your `<option>` tags in the jQuery. The browser is smart and is fixing this for you, but it could cause big problems if you don't close them like I did in my example.

Comment: Yes, from doucmentation: `The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the **matched** set`

Comment: `$('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>').prop('selectedIndex', 1).appendTo('body');` works just fine for me.

Comment: `option` tags don't need to be closed. The HTML is valid as it is.

Comment: @squint - Yes, you're correct. It is usually best practice to close them.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no `option`s with the `selected` attribute when the browser first renders the element, it'll choose the first one.

I thought this was required by the spec, but it turns out that [this was *undefined* in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1) and I can't find anything about it at all in [the current spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-select-element).

There is this, from the HTML 4.01 spec:

> Note. Since existing implementations handle this case differently, the current specification differs from RFC 1866 ([RFC1866] section 8.1.3), which states:
>
> The initial state has the first option selected, unless a SELECTED attribute is present on any of the  elements.
>
> Since user agent behavior differs, authors should ensure that each menu includes a default pre-selected OPTION.

In any case, that does seem to be how it's still handled.

In your first example, the browser doesn't understand the `selectedIndex` property yet because the *DOM* object doesn't exist until after the `select` element is rendered.  That property is created when the browser creates the object.  You can't change the property of an object that doesn't exist yet.

This is confusing... we're dealing with two separate types of objects: a *jQuery* object and a *DOM* object.

In your second example, the browser renders the `select` element and creates an object with a `selectedIndex` property which you immediately change to say that nothing (-1) is selected.

You might find the "placeholder label option" useful if you read about it in the details of [the `select` element specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/the-button-element.html#the-select-element).

Comment: +1. But how do you explain setting `selectedIndex` to 1 works even before the DOM object is created?

Comment: @lunr That's a good question. You've proven my answer wrong, so I can't explain why setting it to -1 before adding it to the DOM doesn't work. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/SFbW8/) shows -1 doesn't work until load even if the elements are part of the DOM before it even gets to the JavaScript.